# Take multiple pictures using Titanium/Appcelerator on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I am working on a small iPhone app using Titanium/Appcelerator. Now what I am trying to do is the following:

- Open the camera to take a picture
- Ask the user if he wants to add another picture (OptionDialog)
- Open the camera again
- {loop here}
- Put the images (saved locally) into an array

I tried putting a OptionDialog into the success event of the camera, but it didn't work as expected.

Comment: can you post your code into a pastie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe something like that.

```
 dialog.addEventListener('click',function(e){
      switch (e.index){
         case 1:
          takeAPicture();
         case default:
           ...          
      };
 });

function takeAPicture(){

  Titanium.Media.showCamera({
    success: function(evtSuccess) {
      dialog.show();    
    },
    ...
  });

};
Titanium.Media.takePicture();
```

Answer (score 0):

what happened putting it into the success event? what exactly did you put into? i would put the

```
dialog.show();
```

into the success event too

Comment: Hi,
so now my option dialog shows up after some tweaking. Here is basically what I got:

http://pastie.org/1697219